# html\ Javascript failing to open existing file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use my html\ javascript to access a PDF file.

I have checked to see if the file exists which it dose however its still returning an error alert stating that the file is not found could someone elaborate on this form me?

```
<p>Zoek voor project Nr: 
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="" />
<a href="#"
   onclick="this.href = ('file://j:/' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '/Tekeningen/TekenwerkDeMar/Definietief/' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '.pdf' )"
   target="_blank">Get</a>
```

Comment: If it returns an error, something are wrong on that. :) Is that a web site or localhosted?

Comment: You can't access local files from the web for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

CHANGE THIS

```
   file://j:/
```

TO

```
   http://localhost // server [use your server url]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use `domain` path instead of file path

```
this.href = ('http://example.com/' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '/Tekeningen/TekenwerkDeMar/Definietief/' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '.pdf');
```

or even instead for in local instance use `localhost` or ipadress with port if configured.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have restrictions on opening local files from a website. If this were allowed, anybody could read your personal files from any website you are visiting.

A) You can upload the file to some webhost to access it via the `http:` instead of `file:` schema.

or

B) You can let the user select the file via `<input type="file" />` and access it via the [DOM File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).